# ElasticSearch Set Processor

Tags: elasticsearch

I am trying to use the Elasticsearch Set Processor functionality to add a Queue wise Constant field to a given index which contains data from multiple Queues. The ElasticSearch documentation is really sparse in this respect.

I am trying to use the below code to create a Set Processor for Index default-*, but somehow it's not working

```
PUT /_ingest/pipeline/set_aht 
{
  "description": "sets queue wise AHT constants",
  "processors": [
    {
      "set": {
        "field": "queueAHTVal",
        "value": "10",
        "if": "queueName == 'A'"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Looking for some howto guidance from anyone who might have previously worked on Set Processor for ElasticSearch

Comment: Can you show a concrete example of what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: I am trying to use the below code to create a Set Processor for Index default-*, but somehow it's not working

PUT /_ingest/pipeline/set_aht
{
  "description" : "sets queue wise AHT constants",
  "processors": [
    {
      "set": {

        "field": "queueAHTVal",

        "value": "10",
        
        "if": "queueName == 'A'"

      }
    }
  ]
  
}

Comment: Please update your question as it's more legible than in comments

Comment: Hi @Val, Thanks for your response. I have updated the question. It would be really very helpful if you could provide some solution guidance

Comment: Can you describe what is not working? What do you get vs what do you expect instead? Show some example

Comment: Hi @Val,

So, when I execute the statement, it gets executed successfully, I get a

{
  "acknowledged" : true
}

However, when I got to Discover and Search for queueName: A, I don't see the field queueAHTVal:10 added for the Index default-*

What I am trying to achieve is that -

For Index default-*, the preprocessor queueAHTVal should be added for a document field queueName whose value should match the condition provided.

I am trying to add screenshots, but guess, I can't add screenshots to comments

Answer (score 2):

I tried to work on a possible suggestion. If i understood your issue well, you want to add a new field based on a field value (queueName) when it equals to A?

If yes, I modified your pipeline and did a test locally.
Here is the updated pipeline code:

```
PUT _ingest/pipeline/set_aht
{
"processors": [
        {
            "set": {
                "field": "queueAHTVal",
                "value": "10",
                "if": "ctx.queueName.equals('A')"
            }
        }
    ]   
}
```

I used the _reindex API so as to ingest the data in another field.

```
POST _reindex
{
"source": {
    "index": "espro"
},
"dest": {
    "index": "espro-v2",
    "pipeline": "set_aht"
}
}
```

The response is:

```
"hits" : [
  {
    "_index" : "espro-v2",
    "_type" : "_doc",
    "_id" : "7BErVHQB3IIDvL59miT1",
    "_score" : 1.0,
    "_source" : {
      "queueName" : "A",
      "queueAHTVal" : "10"
    }
  },
  {
    "_index" : "espro-v2",
    "_type" : "_doc",
    "_id" : "IBEsVHQB3IIDvL59iien",
    "_score" : 1.0,
    "_source" : {
      "queueName" : "B"
    }
  }
```

Let me know if you need help or If I wrongly understood your issue, I will try to help thank you.